# LeetCode question. Two Sum linked list version C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm doing LeetCode problem 2 Add Two Numbers. The description is:

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative
> integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their
> nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum
> as a linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except
> the number 0 itself.
>
> Example:
>
> Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
>
> Output: [7,0,8]
>
> Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.

*Note the two linked list can be in different length*

My idea is to sum each digit from l1 and l2 call it v3. Mod it by 10 (v3%10) to find out the digit I need to insert to the new linked list. And divide it by 10 to figure out if I need to encounter the carry. However, my solution is not returning anything, and I can not figure out why...

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode *dummy = NULL;
        int v3 = 0;
        int carry = 0;
        
        while (l1 && l2  && v3 > 0){
            int v1 = l1->val;
            int v2 = l2->val;
            
            // when l1 reaches the end. Set v1 to 0
            if(l1->next == NULL){
                v1 = 0;
            }
            if(l2->next == NULL){
                v2 = 0;
            }
            
            v3 = (v1 + v2 + carry);
            carry = v3 / 10;
            int insert_value = v3 % 10;
            
            ListNode *newNode = new ListNode(insert_value);
            
            if(dummy == NULL){
                dummy = newNode;
            } else {
                ListNode *head = dummy;
                while (dummy->next){
                    dummy = dummy->next;
                    
                    dummy->next = newNode;
                    dummy = head;
                }
            }
            
            if(l1->next != NULL){
                l1 = l1->next;
            }
            if(l2->next != NULL){
                l2 = l2->next;
            }
        }
        return dummy;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: `v3` is 0 initially, so `v3 > 0` doesn't hold, and the loop never runs.

Comment: Loop condition should be `while( l1 || l2 || carry )` not `and`

Comment: @StephenNewell I tried to do that. But the LeetCode does not prompt me a regular console to step through the code.

Comment: @Slava Thanks. I just fixed that. Now I'm stuck in an infinite loop, feel like the second while loop does not have a break condition

Comment: @ImTrying - Looks like you get sample input, so compile and run it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop condition is not quite correct, it should be something like:

```
ListNode *r = nullptr;
ListNode **curr = &r;
bool carry = false;
while( l1 || l2 || carry ) {
    int v = carry;
    if( l1 ) {
        v += l1->val;
        l1 = l1->next;
    }
    if( l2 ) {
         v += l2->val;
         l2 = ;2->next;
    }
    carry = v >= 10;
    (*curr)->next = new ListNode( v % 10 );
    curr = &(*curr)->next;
}
```

I did not test this code but idea should be clear

Answer (score 0):

@Slave
Okay got it. Had to try out the pointer. But it did work. Thank you!

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode *node = NULL;
        ListNode **cur = &node;
        bool carry = false;
        while(l1 || l2 || carry){
            int val = carry;
            if(l1){
                val += l1->val;
                l1 = l1->next;
            }
            if(l2){
                val += l2->val;
                l2 = l2->next;
            }
            carry = val >= 10;
            *cur = new ListNode(val%10);
            cur = &((*cur)->next);
        }
        return node;

    }
};
```